# How to compare a number in LinkedList using Iterator

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I have two linked list which every list represent a number. 
for example list 1 represent a number of 29 and the second represent a number of 7.
I want to implement operator less equal for these two linkedlist which works following way:
if number which represented by first linkedlist is less equal to the second return true. if not return false.
The most important thing is to go over a each linkedlist just a once. so using size & get methods which defined in linkedlist are not useful.

The issue which I face it when two numbers represented by linkedlists have a different size of length. 
for example 10 ? 1 should return false.
for 1 ? 10 it should return true and also for 10 ? 10. Each number represented by a linkedlist.

I want to go over one or two linkedlist through iterator to understand if the number which represented by first linkedlist is less equal to another.

I wrote a code which works only when numbers represented a same length, for example, 29? 45 or 7 ? 6 and etc.

```
    Iterator<T> iter1 = a1.Iterator();
    Iterator<T> iter2 = a2.Iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        if (!(iter1.next().lessEqual(iter2.next()))) //if iter2 !hasNext this will throw exception; for ex 1?10
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

How can I implement to fix it for different sizes of numbers which represented by linkedlist? Please note every single number in the whole number are allocated in link. for example 294. the number 2 is in first link, 9 in the second and 4 in third link of the current linkedlist.

Comment: You first need to decide what your code should do when the two lists don't have the same size. We can't decide that for you. Should it throw an exception? Only iterate until the end of the shortest list has been found? Always return false? Always return true? Return true if the first list is shorter? How could we know?

Comment: @JohnD just once, but what if one is shorter than the other?

Comment: @Dici if the first is shorter the other so it should return true because the shorter number is always less then longer number.

Comment: Then do just that. Before entering your loop check if one is shorter than the other and return immediately. Then only start your loop.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated the original post with more details. but for question - I always make a less then operator to the first linkedlist. if the first is shorter than other it should return true. if the first longer than other it should return false.

Comment: @JBNizet but if I check if one shorter or longer than other, I need to go a once for all list. size method is not useful in this case, since I want in this method go only and only once a time in each linkedlist. because if they equal I have to go over again.

Comment: If you need to traverse the whole list to know its size, then you need to change the implementation of your list. A standard LinkedList (why use a LinkedList, BTW?) knows its size without having to loop through its nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an exception being thrown, you need to change the loop condition:

```
while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
```

However this is not enough to make your program give the correct answer, for that you need a bit more work.

Assuming that there are no leading zeros, notice that:

- If one number has fewer digits than the other, the shorter number is the smaller
- If both numbers have the same number of digits, then the first different digit decides which one is smaller

The above should be fairly easy to implement if you are using `LinkedList` from the standard library, because it has a `size()` method to check the length without iterating over elements.
If you cannot use the `LinkedList` and you cannot get the size of the list in constant time, then you need to work a bit harder.
Consider these implementation steps:

- Iterate both lists until reaching the end of any of the lists (I already gave you the condition for that).
- In each iteration, compare the digits: if you find a difference, then save that for later use, and do not overwrite it again in the loop. You could use for example a `Boolean firstIsSmaller`, initialized to `null`, and set to `true` or `false` when the first different digit is found, otherwise stay `null` until the end of the loop.
- At the end of the loop, if one of the list did not reach the end, that list is the bigger number.
- If both lists reached the end at the same time, then use `firstIsSmaller` to decide which number is smaller. When `firstIsSmaller` is `null`, that means no difference was found, the numbers are equal. Otherwise the boolean value decides if the first is smaller or not.